# How to Refactor Module using python rope?

Tags: python, rope

I have my project structure as following

```
├── app
│   ├── Country
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── Customer
│   │   └── views.py
```

Where the module 'Country' folder is what I tried to rename it to 'Countries' and every occurrence it is used, and it is also imported in `Customer/views.py` as well.

```
from app.Country.views   import *
....
```

According to this tutorial [Refactoring Python Applications for Simplicity](https://realpython.com/python-refactoring/), I tried it as below:

```
>>> from rope.base.project import Project
>>> 
>>> proj = Project('app')
>>> 
>>> Country = proj.get_folder('Country')
>>> 
>>> from rope.refactor.rename import Rename
>>> 
>>> change = Rename(proj, Country).get_changes('Countries')
>>> proj.do(change)
```

After executing the script, the module folder 'Country' was changed to 'Countries' but its instance where it is used in Customer/views.py does not change accordingly, the import statement in Customer/views.py is still

```
from app.Country.views   import *
```

I expected it should change to `from app.Countries.views   import *` after refactoring, but it did not.

Is there anything else I should do to refactor this successfully? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading `Country` in as a module using `proj.find_module('Country')`?

Comment: @WilliamMiller, I have. I follow the steps as described in question but change `Country = proj.find_module('Country')`. It still does not work. the folder changed but the import statement in Customer/views.py did not change accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun Can you put your project on GitHub?

Comment: @aaron, because it involves company credential source code I am sorry for that. However, I will try to simplify it sufficient example for you to test or anything I could do for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `proj.get_module('app.Country').get_resource()` to rename module.

```
from rope.base.project import Project
from rope.refactor.rename import Rename

proj = Project('app')
country = proj.get_module('app.Country').get_resource()
change = Rename(proj, country).get_changes('Countries')
print(change.get_description())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to work in a virtual environment and/or Django (as the views.py files suggest), you may need to define your PYTHONPATH variable before you start python.

```
>>> export PYTHONPATH=<path-to-app-folder>:<path-to-virtualen-bin>:<other-paths-used-by-your-project>
>>> python
```

Then (code from AnnieFromTaiwan is valid, as well as yours I guess, but did not test it):

```
from rope.base.project import Project
from rope.refactor.rename import Rename

proj = Project('app')
country = proj.get_module('app.Country').get_resource()
change = Rename(proj, country).get_changes('Countries')
proj.do(change)
```